# analyze of Historical Prices for Pepsicola

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

let us consider following data
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=PEP

i have downloaded  this excel sheet and trying to analyze, because  time interval between two  smaple point is one day, so it means that sampling frequency is 1 right?first of all if i  use ploting,i will get following one

[image]

analysis using periodogram

```
[pxx,f]=periodogram(close_pep,[],[],1);

plot(f,pxx)
```

[image]

how can i identify its frequency components?

Comment: Your frequency in _Hertz_ is the number of occurrences _per second_. So if your points are sampled one time per day, your sampling frequency is `Fs = 1/(24*3600)`, which is approx `Fs=1.1574e-4 Hertz`.

Comment: do i need to remove mean from original data?

Comment: Yes, removing the mean usually make the other frequency component appear better (they are not completely obscured by the DC component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've squared the raw data to make sure we can pick out any periodic trends. Looking at the FFT of the data (below) specified we can see no clear peaks. Meaning, its more or less random.Your picture of the spectogram appears to show the same. Keep in mind that a spectogram shows power or density (dB/Hz) on its y axis when compared to a DFT alone but both should be showing the same trend / freq. component on the x axis.

[1] http://tinypic.com/r/qysj0h/8

It is usually better to use welch's method when dealing with time series real-world data. This is the result on the raw closing figures. Again, similar results. This figure however does indicate that that there is more of a short term trend in day-to-day trading than over a shorter term than longer term.

[2] http://tinypic.com/r/1zm15x1/8

Looking at the data manually, I cannot see any trends. Perhaps apart from a period of 2.73 years from ~5000 to ~7000 days.